# How would I handle a boil-over and loss of hops?

Tags: first-time-brewer, boilover

I recently was brewing a 1 gallon kit from Northern Brewer (The White House Honey Ale kit) and instantly after adding the first packet of hops, the entire kettle boiled over. Absolutely instantly, there's nothing I could do to stop it.

I estimate I lost about 1/2 to 1 cup of water and up to 1/4th of my first hops packet (there were no issues when I added the second one later in the brew.) I asked the Northern brewer chatline for help and was only told "Don't try to add more liquid or your beer will be too watery."

Is the loss of the hops going to be an issue in the final flavor? Any recommendations on preventing a future boil-over?

Addtl: I used a 2 gallon kettle as the directions recommend. It's a 1 gallon kit and I used the instructed 5 quarts (1.25 gal) of water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boil sounds like it is more aggressive than it should be. You should try to achieve a "rolling" boil.

I know a lot of brewers keep a spray bottle of water next to their kettle. Spraying the water on the foam will cause it to fall back.

Yes, your beer will not be exactly the same as what it could be, but it is not a major issue.

Here are some things you can also try: http://beersmith.com/blog/2014/05/03/avoiding-a-boil-over-when-home-brewing/

Answer (score 3):

The beer won't be quite as bitter as expected. Don't give up on it, it may still be a perfectly good beer.

Also, preventing boilovers is discussed here: 
[How do you prevent boil-overs?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/how-do-you-prevent-boil-overs)